# How do I make my logs server specific | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Currently, I have a logs on my bot, It works fine but the problem is that it takes logs from all servers that the bot it in. So, how do I make it server specific?

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
 async def on_message_delete(self, message):

        embed = Embed(
            description=f"Message deleted in {message.channel.mention}", color=0x4040EC
        ).set_author(name=message.author, url=Embed.Empty, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

        embed.add_field(name="Message", value=message.content)
        embed.timestamp = message.created_at
        channel=self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my code for message deleting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare message's guild id with yours

Below is the revised code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, message):
    if message.guild.id == YOUR_GUILD_ID:
        embed = Embed(
            description=f"Message deleted in {message.channel.mention}", color=0x4040EC
        ).set_author(name=message.author, url=Embed.Empty, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

         embed.add_field(name="Message", value=message.content)
        embed.timestamp = message.created_at
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```